# Can I custom color (not use quasar color variable) in quasar notify when I use registerType?

Tags: quasar-framework

I use quasar version 1 notify plugin and want to custom color.
But I want to refrain from using quasar palettes.

I register new type of notify type. and set class or color but it doesn't work.
I don't want to change quasar color variables.

```
**notify.vue

Notify.registerType("success", {
      classes: "test1",
      //color : "test2",
});

.test1 {
      color : #effbf4
}


** quasar.variables.scss

$test2 : #effbf4
```

Can I make new color or class to change notify setting?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a Quasar plugin known as toast or snackbar for that I recommend to configure it via the config file as mentioned in the [docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify#notify-api).

```
// quasar.config file

return {
  framework: {
    plugins: [
      'Notify'
    ],
    config: {
      notify: /* look at QuasarConfOptions from the API card */
    }
  }
}
```

Which means altering like below:

```
// quasar.config file

return {
  framework: {
    plugins: [
      'Notify'
    ],
    config: {
      notify: { color: 'primary'}
       /* look at QuasarConfOptions from the API card */
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a live [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-wpplumber?file=README.md) answering your question.